# Where to find Google app maker personal version?

Tags: google-app-maker

Where to find Google App Maker personal version for learning purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [product page](https://gsuite.google.com/products/app-maker/),

> App Maker is included with G Suite Business and Enterprise editions as well as with G Suite for Education.
> If you would like to use Google App Maker and don't have a G Suite account, one of the lowest-cost options is to subscribe to G Suite Business, purchase your own domain name, and create the smallest-tier Google Cloud SQL deployment. Unfortunately none of these are free.

---

**EDIT:**
Please note that App Maker is being discontinued, and has been replaced with AppSheet. It can be purchased separately, or is included with Google Workspace Enterprise.